# Различные варианты конфигурации приложения

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть приложение с полной функциональностью. Это приложение для одного типа пользователей. Они могут редактировать/удалять/добавлять. Но есть и другие пользователи, которым это делать нельзя.

Каким путем пойти, что бы не создавать несколько похожих приложений, но с небольшими различиями по функционалу?

В Delphi я применял такой подход.

```
#IFDEF DISPATCHER
...
#ENDIF

#IFDEF VIEWER
...
#ENDIF
```

В VisualStudio почему-то так

```
#if DEBUG
 // Работает
#endif

#if RELEASE
 // Не работает
#endif
```

Comment: Вы можете, по идее, определять кастомные символы в коде или свойствах проекта.

Comment: Авторизация по паролю с повышением прав либо установка прав пользователя на основе прав текущего пользователя ОС не вариант? Символы условной компиляции не лучший выбор. Имея перед собой два исходника вы наверняка не сможете сказать где какой. И, рано или поздно, запутаетесь...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Все дело в настройках проекта. Конфигурация Debug по умолчанию определяет символы DEBUG и TRACE, конфигурация же Release определяет только TRACE (символа RELEASE не существует).

Вам поможет вот такой способ:

```
#if !DEBUG

#endif
```

Или вот такой:

```
#if DEBUG

#else

#endif
```

Также в свойствах проекта вы можете определить свои символы для условной компиляции. У меня это делается вот так:

[image: скриншот студии]

Но, вообще говоря, для разных режимов работы обычно хорошо подходят настройки и конфигурационные файлы:

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.CanEditFoo) {
  // ...
}
```

Также имеет смысл ограничить доступ пользователя на стороне сервера или СУБД. Если в организации используется Active Directory - то хорошим решением будет авторизация пользователей на основе доменных групп, к которым они относятся.

Comment: стоит добавить что, даже без домена и AD можно ориентироваться на локальные группы пользователей. Этим пользуется весь системный софт Windows, включая SQL и многие сторонние программы типа антивирусов, систем резервного копирования и т.д. Создание соотвествующих локальных групп можно вынести в инсталятор или конфигуратор. Вот прям совсем наглядный пример - инсталятор MS SQL Server или Oracle Server.

Comment: @rdorn это скорее ненаглядные примеры. Все-таки для сетевых СУБД локальные пользователи и группы обычно бесполезны.

Comment: нет, не смысле примера использования, я сам виноват написал не удачно, а в смысле создания и настройки таких групп в процессе конфигурирования. Ну и у независимого сервера просто может не быть других групп, хотя это скорее исключение, чем нормальная практика