# Выбор контента при автоматической сборки в C# ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, build, build-automation

Есть проект C# ASP.NET MVC, в котором, помимо прочего, используются , например, логотип (.png) и файл стилей (.css). Эти файлы должны быть разными для разных сборок. Как можно автоматизировать замену файлов при билде проекта? Можно ли это указать в профиле сборки или где-нибудь в настройках солюшена (для разных сборок будет свой солюшен).
Заранее спасибо

Comment: какая версия VS ? Скорее всего это решается редактированием .csproj и добавлением туда условий типа Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'"

Comment: @koks_rs _VS2013_. В вашем примере _Debug_ - это название профиля? Т.е., я могу заменить _Debug_ на _ReleaseMyProfile1_? Да, я думал над редактирование билд-скрипта проекта, но надеялся на более красивые и встроенные вещи)

Comment: Debug это значение которое хранится в переменной Configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Что-то похожее имеется в проектах на C# (не только MVC).
К примеру Вы можете создать вот такую секцию в файле конфигурации:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UseTestImage" value="false" />       
  </appSettings>
```

Затем добавьте трансформацию файла конфигурации:
щелкаем правой клавишей по файлу конфигурации и выбираем пункт **Add Config Transform**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И в нем пишем что-то другое, отличное от файла по умолчанию:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="UseTestImage" value="true" />       
  </appSettings>
```

И уже где-то в Вашем коде можно обратиться к спрятанному ключу:

```
WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseTestImage"]
```

и в зависимости от условия делать то, что Вам нужно. Так, по идее можно кое-что автоматизировать. Активно пользуюсь трансформациями файла конфигурации:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также можно в коде использовать вот такие записи:

```
#if DEBUG

#else

#endif
```

Вот хороший пример: [Различные варианты конфигурации приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/535152/189339)

Исключение файлов из Build: [Excluding Files and Folders from Deployment](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment)

Comment: Как раз только что наткнулся на статью о трансформации _Web.Config_, но после нее все равно оставался открытым вопрос, можно ли создавать трансформацию кастомного профиля, или это только для стандартных _Debbug_ и _Release_.

Только я все равно пока не понял: вот я использую логотип **logo.png** из папки **logo**. У меня есть два таких файла в папках **logo1** и **logo2**. В зависимости от профиля мне нужно брать картинку из соответствующей папки, при этом не тащить за собой другую папку. Лезть в билд-скрипт проекта и в нем настраивать копирование из папки, указанной в **Web.Config'е**?

Comment: @AndrewZakharov, подтягиваться будут обе папки, так как они прописаны в файле проекта. Если Вы хотите знать на представлении, какое изображение использовать, то можно сделать вот так: `@if (System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["UseTestImage"] == "true")...`

Comment: @AndrewZakharov, по поводу настройки копирования из папки - вот тут я даже не знаю, как Вам помочь. Проект - это единое целое, не думаю, что можно просто взять и отбросить часть проекта из-за того, что конфигурация была изменена. Только если контролировать это вручную - но это не очень хорошо.

Comment: Честно говоря не самое красивое решение из-за подтягивания всех папок. Попробую все-таки оставить в коде путь **logo/logo.png**, а в билд-скрипте копировать содержимое папки **logo1** или **logo2** в **logo**. А отбросить их можно установив свойство _Build Action_ в _none_ у каждого файла. Жаль, к папке такое применить нельзя

Comment: Для исключения файлов/папок из билда в файле **.csproj** добавляются параметры `ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment` и `ExcludeFilesFromDeployment` подробнее можно посмотреть [здесь](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/deployment/advanced-enterprise-web-deployment/excluding-files-and-folders-from-deployment)

Comment: @qzavyer то, что нужно) спасибо)